# nondecreasing rearrangement is equimeasurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, decreasing-rearrangements

Two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are called equi-measurable if $m(\{x:f(x)>t\})=m(\{x:g(x)>t\})$.
Nondecreasing rearrangement of a function $f(x)$ is defined as $$f^*(\tau)=\inf\{t>0:m(\{x:f(x)>t\}\leq\tau\}.$$
Prove that $f^*(\tau)$ and $f(x)$ are equimeasurable.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter? Do you see a point where to start?

Comment: This proof can be found in "Classical Fourier Analysis", Grafakos, Proposition 1.4.5 (12)

Answer (score 0):

Fix $t>0$ et $y\in \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}$. This  is equivalent to say that
$$c_d|y|^d<|\{|f|>t\}|,\qquad \qquad c_d=|B(0,1)|. $$
Assume that
$$\int_{t}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds=0.$$
Then $y\not \in \{|f| > s\}^{*}$ for all $s\geq t$.
That is, for all $s\geq t$ we have
$$c_d|y|^d\geq |\{|f|>s\}| $$
The Fatou lemma implies
$$c_d|y|^d\geq |\{|f|\geq t\}|\geq |\{|f|>t\}|.$$
This is in contradiction with the fact that $c_d|y|^d<|\{|f|>t\}|$. Therefore we deduce $$\int_{t}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds>0.$$
On the other hand, one can check that for every, $0<s< t$ one has $$\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}\subset \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}$$ this entails that,
\begin{equation}\label{eq-inclu t-s}\tag{I}
\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}\subset \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}^{*}~~~\textrm{for all $s\in (0,t)$}.
\end{equation}
this implies that,$$ \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y)  =1 ~~~s\in (0,t)$$

From definition of $f^{*}$,  if $y\in \{|f|>t\}^*$ then we have
$$\begin{align*}
f^{*}(y) &:= \int_{0}^{+ \infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds\\
&= \int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds+ \int_{t}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds\\
& = \int_{0}^{t} ds+\int_{t}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds >t.
\end{align*}$$

Whence, $$\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}\subset \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n:f^{*}(x)> t \right\}.$$
Conversely, suppose, $y\notin \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}$. If $t\leq s$ then analogously to relation \eqref{eq-inclu t-s} we get
$$y\notin \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}^{*}.$$
That is for all $s\geq t$ we get  $$\mathbf{1}_{\{ | f| > s\}^*}(y)=0$$
Hence necessarily for all $s>0$ such that
$ y\in \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}^{*}$ one has $0<s\leq t$. This means that,
$$\sup\left\{s>0 : y\in \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}^{*}\right\}\leq t. $$
We then deduce that,
$$\begin{align*}
f^{*}(y) &:= \int_{0}^{+ \infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds\\
&= \int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds+ \underbrace{\int_{t}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds}_{=0}\leq t
\end{align*}$$
that is  $f^*(y)\leq t$ or that $y\notin \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: f^*(x) > t  \right\}$. We've just prove that,

\begin{equation}\label{eq}\tag{II}
\Bbb R^n\setminus \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}\subset \Bbb R^n\setminus\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: f^*(x) > t \right\}. 
\end{equation}
Which ends the prove by taking the complementary.

Comment: How is the inequality strict in the 4th equation?

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997959/on-rearrangement-of-level-set-ft-ft-text?rq=1